# Не удается подключиться к оборудованию через PHPTelnet

Tags: php, telnet

Возникла проблема с подключением к серверу через telnet используя PHP.

Подключение осуществляю стандартным способом:

```
$fp = fsockopen($ip,23);
$r = '';
do {
    $r.=fread($fp, 8192);
    $s=socket_get_status($fp);
} while ($s['unread_bytes']);
```

В идеале в **$r** я должен увидеть приветственное сообщение и в конце

```
username:
```

На всех серверах я вижу это сообщение и дальше могу прописывать значения **username** и **password**:

```
fputs($this->fp,"$user\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($this->fp,"$pass\r");
sleep(4);
```

Но на одном сервере **$r.=fread($fp, 8192);** вычитывается только один раз, после чего **socket_get_status($fp)** выдает, что больше нет **['unread_bytes']**.
Соответственно дальнейшие попытки ввести пользователя и пароль не дают результата. Подключиться и выполнить что-либо на этой машине не получается.

Пока что обнаружил только одну аномалию, если подключаться через консоль, то на сервере, к которому удается подключиться, шапка входа выглядит так:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
  *** Hello message ***

User Access Verification

Username:
```

А на проблемном сервере так:

```
Escape character is '^]'.

  *** Hello message ***

User Access Verification

Username:
```

Как можно заметить, перед приветственным сообщением находится пустая строка. Как от нее избавиться, не понятно.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать PHPTelnet https://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/

Comment: у меня эта библиотека и установлена.

Comment: Ну так работайте через эту библиотеку, а не сокеты

Comment: Я через нее и работаю, просто описал для простоты кусок кода из этой библиотеки, на котором возникает проблема. Вы же понимаете, что эта библиотека так же работает через сокеты?

Comment: Была когда-то подобная проблема, решена была подбором "заголовков" в функции инициализации класса PHPTelnet()

Comment: Можете подсказать, по какому принципу их подбирать?

Comment: На сколько я помню, заголовки из себя представляют telnet-команды. например 1 команда-  chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x1F) 0xFB-команда,0x1F-подкоманда. Отправляется от 2-х до 4-х заголовков. На этом этапе идет согласование между сервером и клиентом. Подбирал прослушивая пакеты через Wireshark (когда соединялся стандартным клиентом) и перенося потом эти данные в скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать такие "заголовки"

$this->conn1=chr(0xff).chr(0xfd).chr(0x03).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x18).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x1f).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x20).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x21).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x22).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x27).chr(0xff).chr(0xfd).chr(0x05).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x23);

$this->conn2=chr(0xff).chr(0xfa).chr(0x18).chr(0x00).chr(0x78).chr(0x74).chr(0x65).chr(0x72).chr(0x6d).chr(0x2d).chr(0x32).chr(0x35).chr(0x36).chr(0x63).chr(0x6f).chr(0x6c).chr(0x6f).chr(0x72).chr(0xff).chr(0xf0);

$this->conn3=chr(0xff).chr(0xfd).chr(0x03).chr(0xff).chr(0xfb).chr(0x01);

У меня в одном из скриптов такое работает. Суть в том, что некоторые telnet-сервера запрашивают тип терминала у клиента, ответ на этот запрос $this->conn2